# jQuery to remove an option from drop down list, given option's text/value

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu

I have a drop down list and would like to remove an option from it, given the text/value of that particular option. Is it possible using jQuery? Just like 'append' which adds an option to the drop down list, is there a function to remove an option?

I tried searching for it but all I got were examples where the entire set of options in the drop down list are removed, which is not what I seek.

cheers

Answer (score 171, accepted):

`$("option[value='foo']").remove();`

or better (if you have few selects in the page):

`$("#select_id option[value='foo']").remove();`

Comment: what if foo was a variable ? how would the syntax then be ?

Comment: @JeffJaffery: `$("option[value='" + foo + "']").remove();`

Comment: Thanks @Y.Shoham. This is how i used it 
    $(#select_id).find('option[value=' + foo + ']').remove();

Comment: @JeffJaffery: it's unclear from your note if it worked for you or not. But, you must put apostrophes around `#select_id`, like this: https://jsfiddle.net/8txh9t52/

Answer (score 25):

Once you have localized the dropdown element

```
dropdownElement = $("#dropdownElement");
```

Find the `<option>` element using the JQuery [attribute selector](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)

```
dropdownElement.find('option[value=foo]').remove();
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks! (Everywhere I went, I found information on how to select an individual option with a selector. I was looking for how to remove an option given you already had the dropdown selected, which seemed like the more typical use case.)

Comment: this is the efficient answer than previous one :D

Comment: This is how I like to do things, first time I see somebody else has the discipline to be explicit and clean like this. Are there any other resources on this way of using JQuery?

Answer (score 5):

```
$('#id option').remove();
```

This will clear the Drop Down list. if you want to clear to select value then `$("#id option:selected").remove();`

Answer (score 1):

I know it is very late but following approach can also be used:

```
<select id="type" name="type" >
    <option value="Permanent" id="permanent">I am here to stay.</option>
    <option value="toremove" id="toremove">Remove me!</option>
    <option value="Other" id="other">Other</option>
</select>
```

and if I have to remove second option (id=toremove), the script would look like

```
$('#toremove').hide();
```

Comment: This works whether you are hard-coding the values into your dropdown or dynamically adding something you want to tag and take away later. I added an option dynamically using `theField.prepend('<option id="toRemove" selected="selected" value="TBD">TBD</option>');` such that it included an ID like above, then tried taking it away using `theField.find('id:toRemove').remove()` - but that didn't work. So I tried `$('#toRemove').remove()` (similar to yours above, but because I re-add it when I need to show it, I do `remove()` instead of `hide()`) and this works. Thanks for the idea.

Answer (score 0):

I have used the above option to .hide entries from 2 drops down boxes (first you select the city, then you selected the area within that city). It works fine on screen but the hidden options are still selectable via keyboard inputs.

Answer (score 0):

Many people had difficulty in using this keyword when we have iteration of Drop-downs with same elements but different values or say as Multi line data in USER INTERFACE. :
Here is the code snippet :
$(this).find('option[value=yourvalue]');

Hope you got this.

Answer (score -1):

First find the class name for particular select.

```
$('#id').val('');
$('#selectoptionclassname').selectpicker('refresh');
```

Comment: That blanks the value, not hides the available option.