# how to remove the combo box value from database in jsp page that uses struts and hibernate?

Tags: hibernate, jsp, struts-1

Hi I have four combo box as same if one option is selected  atonce it should not be appeared in other combo boxes ie: no repeated value should not be selected by user? the problem is the values are from databases? I am new to this  please help?

how to remove the combo box value from database in the jsp page when an option is selected  that uses struts and hibernate ?

following is the sample code.

```
<html:optionsCollection  property="ListName" value="value" label="name5"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Removing from database ??what an elegant way..*

Don't delete it from database.Use some scripting on client side itself and `hide` or `remove` from `combo` by using some script  or with some proper messages.

What happens if he/she selected one value in first combo,So then you delete that option from database.What if he wants to change the selection again ??As you deleted from DB,you never get tit back.

My suggestion is that `hide/remove` that value from `Combobox` with some [Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1982449/jquery-to-remove-an-option-from-drop-down-list-given-options-text-value).

Comment: Thanks for your reply...I just want to hide it from the user...not remove it from db..thank you very much and i ll try ...it