# Last value of dropdown is missing once clicked on button using MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, html-select

If i select last value of dropdown and click on search button then dropdown looses its value,However if i select anyother value and click on button then dropdown did not loose that value.

I am not sure why its happening.

Here is the link of the website:

http://www.ourplanettravel.com.au/

You can see dropdownlists on right side:

once you choose destination    "Tasmania" from 1st dropdown and  "Tours & Cruises"  from 2nd dropdown and click on search button then 2nd dropdown looses its value( "Tours & Cruises").
However if you select any other value from 2nd dropdown then that value is not looses.I don't know why its happening.

Here is my code:

```
   <select id='TourismType' name="TourismType"> 
       <option value=''>--Choose Tourism Type--</option>   
       {{if $item.data.oTourismType}} 
         {{each  $item.data.oTourismType}}

    <option value='${Text}'>${Text}</option>
     {{/each}} 

   </select> 
     {{/if}}
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, what's the name of that rendering engine?

Comment: @DanielImms can you please check this link.  http://www.ourplanettravel.com.au/

Comment: when you look at the source on the dropdown is there anything irregular about that last record in the drop down?  do you get any errors in the console when that record is selected?

Comment: @MattBodily  can you please check this  link:  http://www.ourplanettravel.com.au/

Comment: if I had to guess it is the & in the name.  try removing that to see if you still have issues.  if that is the problem look into escaping it

Comment: @MattBodily i have no access of database???

Comment: can i put anythng in code to remove &???

Answer (score 0):

From your code (I looked it up) you are using jquery templates so hopefully this will work for you

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $.each("#TourismType", function(index, item){
            item = item.replace("&", "");
        });
    });
</script>
```

Everything is correct here except I am not 100% certain that is the correct way to select all of the elements in the dropdown.  Since we have figured out where you issue is see if you can get this to work and if you still have issues you should create a new question specific to that.

Comment: I don't have remote software.  Please take a look at this link and replace the remove with the replace code above,  hopefully this helps.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1982449/jquery-to-remove-an-option-from-drop-down-list-given-options-text-value

Comment: no need of software..."Remote desktop connection" is by default in every system.please check in your system.

Comment: you definitely don't want to give out credentials to remote your computer.  I am at work and don't have time to remote anyway,  try the suggestion in my previous comment to see if you can get it to work.  good luck

Comment: this is my code:   <select id='TourismType' name="TourismType"> 
       <option value=''>--Choose Tourism Type--</option>   
       {{if $item.data.oTourismType}} 
         {{each  $item.data.oTourismType}}

    <option value='${Text}'>${Text}</option>
     {{/each}} 

   </select> 
     {{/if}}

Comment: that is the code for creating your dropdown.  the code and link in my comment would go in a script tag at the bottom of your page to remove the & from there.  I don't recognize the syntax you are using for your dropdown to be able to help you change that

Comment: can you post your javascript code so we can look at it and see if we can fix that?

Comment: my code is in script tag...<script id="dpBusTemp" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl">   <select id='TourismType' name="TourismType"> <option value=''>--Choose Tourism Type--</option> {{if $item.data.oTourismType}} {{each $item.data.oTourismType}} <option value='${Text}'>${Text}</option> {{/each}} </select> {{/if}}  </script>

Comment: its taking #TourismTypein item..i have checked in alert(item);

Comment: i have tried one thing by  passing $Value like this in my existing code. <option value='${Value}'>${Text}</option>..it solves the issue of last selection but first time it displays  --Choose Tourism Type--