# How link two chosen fields removing options from each other

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-chosen

I have two fields that have the same options. I want to make sure that when the user selects one option from one of them, the opposite field will have this same option removed.

So, if an user selects T. Edson as `Recipient`, this option will be removed on `CCs` field.

[image]

I tried the following as someone said [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1982449/jquery-to-remove-an-option-from-drop-down-list-given-options-text-value) but doesn't seem to work.

```
    function checkAddressFields() {
        var recipientField = $('#id_recipient');
        var ccsField = $('#id_ccs');
        console.log("Removing duplicate");
        $("#id_ccs option[value='"+recipientField.val()+"']").remove();
        ccsField.trigger("chosen:updated");
    }
    $('#id_recipient').on('change', checkAddressFields);
    $('#id_ccs').on('change', checkAddressFields);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this example..

```js
$select = $('.select');
$select.on('change', function() {
  var val = $(this).val();
  $notThis = $select.not($(this));
  $notThis.find('option').show();
  $notThis.find('option[value=' + val + ']').hide();
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select class="select">
  <option>Select rec</option>
  <option value="option1">Option 1</option>
  <option value="option2">Option 2</option>
  <option value="option3">Option 3</option>
  <option value="option4">Option 4</option>
  <option value="option5">Option 5</option>
</select>

<select class="select">
  <option>Select cc</option>
  <option value="option1">Option 1</option>
  <option value="option2">Option 2</option>
  <option value="option3">Option 3</option>
  <option value="option4">Option 4</option>
  <option value="option5">Option 5</option>
</select>
```

Comment: `ccsField.find("option[value='"+recipientField.val()+"']").hide();` Worked like a charm. Thanks. :o)

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the whole code, it may be a bit tricky, but try something like this (making sure that recipientField.val() is passed to checkAddressFields()):

```
$("#id_ccs option[value='+recipientField.val()+']").remove();
```